# react native *without* a mobile device

Tags: react-native

At the moment my development environment is hyper-v based and for whatever reason, I cannot get a hyper-v vm to recognize that my android device is connected.

Before I spend hours configuring dual boot, or something else, I would like to know if react native development is feasible without a device?

I can imagine my developer experience will be less than ideal, but as long as I can create an .apk file, I should be able to get my app onto a device eventually.

Are there any other technical limitations that I should be aware of, or will using the various emulators be adequate?

Comment: It's always best to use a device when you can, at least at regular intervals.  Not testing on a real device for a long time is likely to store up all kinds of trouble (esp.performance, networking etc)

Comment: There is a big risk that getting the app onto the device will prove to be a big enough hurdle that I don't bother.